# Output not displaying when attempting to connect to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I recently set up a lamp server in an attempt to create a website. My code is as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM nes";

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','gameRankings');
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while ($row < mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['ranking'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . ': ' . $row['review'] . ' ' . $row['releaseYear'] .'<br>';
}
mysqli_close($db);
?>

 <h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

The program runs fine and outputs the data I want when I run it using php index.php however when I go to load the site into a browser nothing displays except the heading. If I were to move my the $db connector line to the top of the code then not even the heading displays. There are no errors being thrown in the apache logs either. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here!

Comment: How are you _loading the site into the browser_ ? What do you see in the address bar on the browser

Comment: `while ($row < mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` So when my `mysqli_fetch_array()` is greater than the previous fetch. Comparing 2 arrays with a `<` operator. Programming languages are simplistic. Unless you overload the operator (not able to do so in PHP) and define the rules that makes say why 1 array greater than the other; A language does not have the capability to understand why something is greater. Yes, it understands `2 > 1` because it simply has more bits. Something as complex as an array though? Even a string is far fetched.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am opening it on another computer on the network through firefox. All I see in the address bar is my ip address of the linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while ($row < mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

With

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

That will update `$row` each loop, with the value from database, and display the info you want.

Comment: yea I actually had it set up like that originally. My bigger concern at the moment is that nothing is showing up on the web page and there are no errors being displayed. When I run the program from the command line it does display information from the database so I know it's connecting and grabbing the data.

Answer (score 1):

Do these two steps and you will get your result .

1. Remove this statement :

   ```
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   ```
2. Re-write the while statement as :

   ```
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       //Your Code
   }
   ```
3. If you still got no result , then check your database tables whether they have any records or not .

Comment: The bigger concern at the moment is getting something to display on the webpage. If I removed the database connection line it will actually load the html properly but renders the rest of the code I have useless.

Comment: @Anthony Fenicchia, please check your database whether it has any data or not . If nothing is getting displayed after connecting to db , then check the table and field names properly .

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had a good answer as to what fixed this but I came in this morning to it functioning properly. I also made the other adjustments that were mentioned. This was my first post and I really appreciate the feedback everyone gave!